# Error on If statement after multiple executions

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm receiving an error on a line of code after it executes multiple times.  It is occurring when it reaches the same level of execution (same place in the goal the macro is attempting to accomplish).  The overall program is meant to generate multiple emails and send them to different companies with different email attachments.  It works until it gets to about 2/3rds the way down where i get a 1004 error.  Any ideas?  ** is location of error. The code below is a smaller snippet of a much larger routine.

Thanks!

```
'sets row_counter = row_num to avoid iteration over unecessary rows in ReportsbyFirm and resets continue to True for PDF attachment phase
    continue = True
    row_counter = row_num

    With outMail
        .To = firmEmail
        .Subject = reportDate 
        .body = body

        Do While continue = True

           ** If reportsByFirm.Cells(row_counter, firmcol) = cFirm Or reportsByFirm.Cells(row_counter, firmcol) = iFirm Then
                pdfLocation = getPDFs(cFirm, iFirm, row_counter, reportsByFirm, trMaster, trSeparate, trName, reportDate)
                .Attachments.Add (pdfLocation)
                row_counter = row_counter + 1

            ElseIf row_counter <> lRowReportsByFirm Then
                row_counter = row_counter + 1

            Else
                continue = False
            End If
        Loop
        .Display
    End With
```

Comment: What are the values of `row_counter`, `firmcol` when it falis?

Comment: @TimWilliams Firm column is static at 5 and row_counter is 28.  LRowReportsByFirm in this circumstance is 34

Comment: What is the text of the error, and do either of those cells contain an error value?

Comment: Change the value of that cell. Does the error still occur?

Comment: Text of the error is Application-defined or object-defined error. No error value in the cell, but when I change the value of the cell to another company that's already in the sheet it works.  Later on, the company appears again and it works with that one as well..so it is specifically that location in the spreadsheet for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was occurring in the loop counter.  The logic was not satisfying always ultimately satisfying to false, which would lead to row_counter ending up at 104K + value.  Fixed by this

```
    Do While continue = True

            If reportsByFirm.Cells(row_counter, firmcol) = cFirm Or reportsByFirm.Cells(row_counter, firmcol) = iFirm Then
                pdfLocation = getPDFs(cFirm, iFirm, row_counter, reportsByFirm, trMaster, trSeparate, trName, reportDate)
                .Attachments.Add (pdfLocation)
                row_counter = row_counter + 1

            ElseIf row_counter < lRowReportsByFirm Then
                row_counter = row_counter + 1

            ElseIf row_counter >= lRowReportsByFirm Then
                continue = False
            End If
        Loop
        .Display
    End With
```